# Meta keywords before doctype declaration?

Tags: dreamweaver, doctype, meta-tags

I recently was browsing a local web design firm's portfolio and found all their sites' code begins as such:

```
<meta name="keywords" content="a whole bunch of keywords for their site"> 
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"> 
<html> 
...
```

I was able to determine that the pages were generated by dreamweaver (at least in part).

Did dreamweaver do this, or did their "developer" just paste the code at the top of the document.

It is my impulse that this is bad practice and it might work incorrectly on some platforms but it got me wondering as to whether or not their may be a reason for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a terrible practice and invalid HTML. I bet that this would throw IE directly into quirks mode.

But as for your question, either the developer is a script kiddie and shoved the `<meta>` tag in there with little knowledge of the outcomes, or Dreamweaver did it. I hope it was Dreamweaver...

Comment: No way was this something that Dreamweaver did by itself. The code was modified my hand, or their content system (if they have one) was set to cause the meta tags to be placed where they are.

Comment: [According to @Rich](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20414237/363701) it *is* some weird Dreamweaver behavior/bug(?)

Answer (score 2):

FYI - just had this issue and Dreamweaver does not put the meta tags in the correct position automatically. Cursor must be placed beforehand into an editable region.